# Creating/Rendering Activity before starting it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

We use different activities to navigate through our app. One of them is very complex and contains a lot of nested views/images etc, so when I use`startActivity(intent1)` in the activity before it, there is a short delay and it feels/looks laggy. 
All the information needed to create the content views is known in advance.

So my question is: is there a smart way to prerender/preload the activity or its content view?

As i figured the intend only holds information about the next activity but no instance of the activity itself, so i assume there is no way to tell the intend to create the activity before i call the startMethod.

One idea i hat was to create a static view before starting the activity and set this view as contentView in the `onCreate()` method. But it seems like a bad hack to me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) to find where your sluggishness is, then fix it.

Comment: i used traceview already and optimized it to 1/5 of the time but there its still too slow and there is not much room for improvement. but thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be not to start a completely new activity but using a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) or [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). Switching between Views should be then nearly instantaneous and you also get the chance to easily apply animations.

If that is not possible you could start a new activity but put a ViewSwitcher in there. The first View would be a progress bar. The second view is inflated and added to the Switcher in a background thread.

Comment: yes, and i will do this with my next app, but the problem is that it would screw up the navigation and concept of the app if i used it like this. i would have to override the back-button for example, since that is one way to navigate throught the app.

Comment: Now i dont know your navigation concept but my guess is that from a users perspective the only difference would be the back key behavior which could be relatively simple to emulate. Switch to first view if second view is visible, else call finish().

Comment: and i guess the flip/page animation will be different to the others. and its pretty difficult to emulate this because each android version/branding has its own animation page between acitivities.

Comment: You can easily customize all switch animations. Either between activities or betweens views using ViewFlipper